# How to display an object a day where i have 30 objects from an array in ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to display quotes in my app on daily basis like 30 days a month and i have an array of 30 quotes and i want to display single quote on a day? How can i do this in ionic 4?

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please Share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code from your part this is all I can do:

```
const quotes: string[] = [
    'Quote 1',
    'Quote 2'
     ...
];
const d: Date = new Date();
const key: number = d.getDate() - 1;
const quoteOfTheDay: string = quotes[key];
```

Comment: This is not working as i want it to do, i am working on ionic angular app